# How to make a loading screen state transition to game level state?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to make my basic loading screen transition over to game level screen. So what i wanted to do is, once the loading screen is active (or has appeared onscreen), I want at this point to start loading my game state. What it is doing at the moment is loading everything at the start, and this does take a while.

So currently my project starts off with a main menu. Then when i press enter, its starts the loading screen. I have my manual state change using keypresses like so:

```
void Game::update()
{
    static bool enterPreviouslyPressed = false;
    static bool escapePreviousPressed = false;

    const Uint8 *keys = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

    if (keys[::SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE] && !escapePreviousPressed && typeid(*fsm->getState()) == typeid(GameState))
    {
        fsm->setState(menuState);
    }
    else if (keys[::SDL_SCANCODE_RETURN] && !enterPreviouslyPressed && typeid(*fsm->getState()) == typeid(MainMenuState))
    {
        fsm->setState(loadingState);
    }
    else if ((keys[::SDL_SCANCODE_RETURN] && !enterPreviouslyPressed) && typeid(*fsm->getState()) == typeid(LoadScreenState))
    {
        fsm->setState(gameState);
    }
    else if (keys[::SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE] && !escapePreviousPressed && typeid(*fsm->getState()) == typeid(MainMenuState))
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    enterPreviouslyPressed = keys[::SDL_SCANCODE_RETURN] != 0;
    escapePreviousPressed = keys[::SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE] != 0;

    fsm->update();
}
```

I did this to initially does this so i could change states manually to check that everything works. I was wondering if there was an easy(ish) way, like boolean flags for example or another simpler way to do this. I wasn't able find any tutorials online so wondering if someone knows the best solution as to how to do this. I did see a question on here, kindda similar but I wasn't sure if it answered my question as the person did this in threads which I am not familiar with how to implement. Apologies if I dont seem to have the logic correct - so please advise otherwise.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Do you want to know if there are easier ways to handle state machines?

Answer (score 0):

Looks fairly standard, except I would simplify it by keeping two keyboard state variables declared as class variables, like:

```
const Uint8 *curKeys  = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL), *prevKeys;

// ...

void Game::update() {

    prevKeys = curKeys;
    curKeys =  = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

    //and so then compare curKeys to prevkeys 
    //and ditch the booleans
    // ...
}
```